# C# winform Unhandled exception occured after running the application on user login

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have developed an C# WinForms application with the setup project in Visual Studio 2010 and am using SqlClient, .NET Entity Framework 4 and Crystal Reports 2011 as well.

I installed my WinForms application on other computer for testing purposes, the installation was successful. I have installed .NET EF 4 on the testing computer as well and when I run the installed application and when I click on login it give `unhandled exception...` error:

[image: this Error]

I really could not figure out the actual problem and am stuck. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: put the try catch block on your login click event and handle exception and see what exactly cause the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)